# How am I allowed to go "over-memory" in Xcode execution

Tags: c, xcode, macos, memory

I've written a function that will allocate more memory that I have available on my machine (16GB), yet it seems running that function doesn't have any affect on my actual machine (the "Memory used" under the Memory Pressure section, at the bottom of the page, doesn't change at all while I'm running it). Here is a screenshot showing this:

[image]

Why doesn't the mrmoy change while running this program and how am I able to get up to "37GB"? Does it use 'fake memory' or something while it's debugging and has break points?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most modern operating systems, certainly Mac OS or Linux, use [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory). Virtual memory is an ability the operating system has to take a page of disk space and map it into addressable memory. This memory has a *virtual* address space. This means the address of any memory is not a physical RAM location, but a location that is mapped to the page of disk. This virtualization of address spaces is done by a component of the computer called the MMU (Memory Management Unit).

The memory pressure does not change because the OS recognizes the large call you made to `malloc` will not fit entirely in RAM.

Comment: when does the virtual memory become ram memory then? For example, in Photoshop, I'll easily go over a few GBs of memory and my computer will instantly 'feel it'. How is it possible to tell when virtual memory because 'real' memory?

Comment: @TagC198 When you initialize it to some value, like `0`. You can use `memset(ptr, 0, size)` to test it out.

Comment: yes as @JL2210 said uninitialized memory is just reserved by the OS so it's not occupied. If you use `calloc`, `memset`, or start writing to it you will see a difference.